# What is YYYYPPP format

Tags: vb.net, date-formatting

I am working on a export functionality and one of the requirments is to display accounting period in YYYYPPP format.

Can anyone please explain what is YYYYPPP format

Comment: there is no [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) string in .NET that is `PPP`. You should probably state from where you got that requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is about time information where YYYY is the fiscal year and PPP is the period of that fiscal year. For example, 2017001 represents the first period in fiscal year 2017.

Often used in Analysis Budget Management tools like SAP. The standard format for entering periods is YYYYPPP or YYYY then PPP.

Comment: Interesting, where did you get this info?

Comment: Thank you so much @Kurt Van